# Changing CSS animations visibility with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I've been following directions from [Justin Aguilar's Site](http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/index.html#how) to add some CSS Animations to my website. It's well put together and seems fairly straightforward. However I've been having a major problem triggering entrance animations.

Being fairly new to this I understand this question can be completely inane, but I've been toying with it for the last few days with no success.

To create an entrance the element's visibility is initially set to 'hidden'. Then javascript is supposed to trigger the animation by adding the .pullUp class which causes the element to become visible and animate.It seems pretty simple, but all of my elements begin animating as soon as the page loads or they remain invisible.

I could really use some help. Here is a [Link to the code on JFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/nolakat/AvmQm/)

```
   <img src="img/apple.png" id="apple" class="pullUp" /> 

   <script= "text/css">

.pullUp{
    animation-name: pullUp;
    -webkit-animation-name: pullUp; 

    animation-duration: 1.1s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.1s;

    animation-timing-function: ease-out;    
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;    

    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%; 

    visibility: visible !important;             
    }
</script>

<script>

$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('#apple').each(function(){
  var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

  var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (imagePos < topOfWindow+150) {
      $(this).addClass(".pullUp");
    }
  });
</script>
```

Basically I just need my image to become visible and animate when the image is scrolled to.

It's possible that my site's Bootstrap Frameworks could be the source of the problem, but I don't see why it would. Also please know that I use External Style Sheets and just included all of the code here for convenience. Any insight or help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [forked your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3srnH/2/)

1. You were missing `});` at the end of your code block. That's why jQuery wasn't working.
2. Your image had the `pullUp` class already added, so the animation was starting right away.

Comment: Originally I had the right idea about the pullUp class being added later, but since it didn't work (thanks to the missing semicolons) I gave up. At least I know I wasn't completely off track, but still a dumb mistake. I'll make sure to check my closing brackets more carefully next time. Thanks again!

Comment: @Nolakat If an answer is satisfactory you can click the arrow to the left of the answer to mark it as correct

Comment: @Zeaklous I tried as soon as I read the comments, but Overstack is telling me still need 15 reputation points. I guess my gratitude will have to suffice for now :(

Comment: @Nolakat That's to upvote. I'm referencing the check mark below those arrows. It'll even give you 2 reputation for doing so!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your CSS where you have floats you did not specify a position (i.e position:relative or position:absolute). That's crucial for this type of thing (edit: apparently not, as show by the answer below).

After adding in position:relative to those elements it seems to work, however you might need to modify the animation as the effect seems quite minimal.

Comment: Thanks. I've specified the positions and the animation still runs. Unfortunately it runs as soon as I load the page. The javascript portion that is supposed to trigger the animation when the element is scrolled to doesn't seem to be working. Do you think it's something in the JS code?

Comment: Most likely, though I'm only assuming. I would look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/grnQA/ and try to play around with that.

This javacript code: http://jsfiddle.net/dueWG/10/ also does the same thing as the above but detects for ie6/ie7